# The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

When I was restarting the apche2, I was getting this message..

```
sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

and when I was typed the `localhost/phpmyadmin`, it showing the message

> -NOT FOUND The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Please help me in this.

Comment: Hi There!! Can you try `sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin` & then `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` on a terminal and let me know.  **Sudo** requires admin password, therefore; please provide accordingly. :)

Comment: I'm guessing you have `phpmyadmin` installed. If that's the case, you shouldn't have to symlink `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` like above mentioned, however you should check that you have `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` and that it has been enabled in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`. If it is found in `conf-available` but not in `conf-enabled` then you will need to enable it using `sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf` or `sudo a2enconf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then try reinstalling phpmyadmin using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall phpmyadmin` - this will automatically setup `phpmyadmin` for you.

Answer (score 118):

Have you tried to:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line to the end of the file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: To improve answer quality, please explain what these instructions are actually doing and why this needs to be done. Thanks

Comment: This saved my life. I nearly shat myself.

Comment: Works on ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 17):

I believe this is because You haven't configure your phpmyadmin with the apache server well. If you installed the apache server and phpmyadmin using `sudo apt-get install` (Because you can install them using source code etc.) below procedure may works for you.

`sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

now type 
`localhost/phpmyadmin` in web browser address bar

if you did everything correctly now you can see the phpmyadmin on the browser.

(Due to your installation method of apache restarting the server or other thing may different. If it is, then you have to do manually what commands meant to do (this description is believing you are very new to apache in linux :) ))

Answer (score 8):

On Ibrahim's answer, I used the nano in the terminal instead of gedit, cause I could not get gedit to work.

Root Terminal Steps

1. Paste in terminal, this will open in the terminal Nano editor:

   ```
   nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
2. Then add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
   ```
3. <kbd>ctrl-o</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-x</kbd> to save and exit.
4. Then paste in terminal: restart apache:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

Answer (score 0):

just went through this myself with a clean install of 20.04 in a VM ... I believe the 404 issue has to do with my creating a /var/www/[someotherdomain] ... all of the instructions with regards to apache, lamp and PHPMyAdmin appear to expect users to be using /var/www/HTML ... based on the instructions in this thread, after I substituted [someotherdomain] for [html] in the ln command, PHPMyAdmin now works from an intranet web request ... Mamp and Xampp kind of make us lazy by doing all this setup automatically ... not sure if someone has already written a dependency thread for PHPMyAdmin but would make it easier for those of us that don't do this every day ... trying to create a test environment for some GitHub PHP and Java stuff and just spent several days to get something set up that is usable ... Xampp has the latest PHP which for some reason isn't backward compatible and it wasn't clear if Xampp could load an older version of PHP ... Mamp is ok in that it has the correct version of PHP but the PHP stuff I downloaded only has instructions related to a Unix platform ... so I started with 16.04 32b and ran into irreconcilable configuration issues ... tried 18.04 64b again with multiple configuration issues ... now finally have a working 20.04 64b with PHP and MySQL DB

What I had to do to get PHPMyAdmin working was:

- Install and configure mySql
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04
- Install and configure apache2 and lamp
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04
- Install and configure PHPMyAdmin
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04
- reading between the lines debug the 404 issue
  [The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668734/the-requested-url-phpmyadmin-was-not-found-on-this-server)